# Loki's Blessing clan upgrade in Yggdrasil during a game of Blood Rage

Tags: blood-rage

The card says *If you lose a battle, you may invade that province with a warrior for free*. Does that mean that if you lose in Yggdrasil you get to invade Yggdrasil with a warrior as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes.**

From the FAQ:

> **Q. May Yggdrasil be invaded if I lose a battle using Loki’s Blessing (allows
>   warrior to invade without cost the province where the battle was lost)?**
>
> A. Yes, Loki’s Blessing allows you put a Warrior in Yggdrasil.